# Debug angular2 modules with source mapping

Tags: npm, angular, typescript1.7

Can you suggest if it is possible to debug code for Angular2 modules with ts source mapping in browser. I used "npm install" command according to https://angular.io/guide/quickstart to install my project. Source mapping is available for my code but not for angular2 modules.

Answer (score 0):

Source mapping is for your code not for angular. By default when you running not bundled angular2 application it will load angular2 modules in browser and when you run your application  you can debug through the angular2 modules if that is what you want!